# In X-Men: First Class who are the mutant children found by professor X?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

In the movie, when Professor X uses Cerebro for the first time, he is able to detect some mutant children.

I believe the first one was Storm, since she was a little girl with white hair.

But who were the other kids? Is this info revealed somewhere or they are just some random mutant children with undisclosed identities?

[image: Possibly Storm]
[image: Possibly Cyclops]

Comment: I had trouble finding screenshots online. [Storm?](http://media.comicvine.com/uploads/0/40/1830484-xfc2_super.png) [Cyclops in background?](http://www.fxguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/6_cinesite_XMen_First_Class.jpg)

Comment: Can't find a screenshot, but Leela Turanga is one of them.

Comment: I think that's PhoneGirl in the background on the first shot.

Comment: The boy with glasses is most likely Cyclops and the white-haired girl Storm, as already pointed out. Phone-girl and pony-tail girl are a mistery. Pony-tail girl might be Jean Grey or Rogue

Comment: Doesn't First Class take place in the 60's? These kids could not possibly be Storm and Cyclops as they would be too old to be the characters seen in the first X-Men movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best I can make out:

- Boy in sunglasses: Cyclops (definitely)
- Girl with white hair: Storm (definitely)
- Girl with pony-tail: Jean Grey (likely)
- Girl on telephone: Jubilee or Karma (leaning towards Karma)

There was also a boy reading a comic book as well, I haven't found any clues to his identity.

Comment: Intentions of movie-makers aside, the entire *First Class* movie takes place in 1962. These children would be in their 50's by the 21st century.

Comment: Not quite sure about Storm, although it could be obvious by it's appareance, she grow up in an african tribe being considered a goddess

Comment: Unfortunately, while these may have been the intended references at the time, the fact that First Class took place in '62 and X-Men: Apocalypse takes place in the 80's and has Cyclops, Storm, Jean and Jubilee all as teenagers, it makes all of these wrong in-universe.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the white haired girl is Storm and the boy in sun glasses is Cyclops. But I have doubts but I'm pretty sure that the pony tail girl is Jean Grey. I like to think that they put Cyclops and Jean in the same shot to hit that they would end up together or to make it more simple to figure out it was Jean since they are a couple.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Although it's a good one, your answer does not add any information to the previous answers of this question. Also, the tone is not quite friendly. If it was so obvious, the OP would have not asked the question. Please refrain from using such sentences next time